# How to specify image height only and keep aspect ratio in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, nextjs-image

I want to specify my image height only and keep the image aspect ratio without hardcoding the width.

In a traditional `img` element I can do so:

```
<img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" height={30} />
```

But if I try using `next/image`:

```
<Image src="/logo.png" alt="logo" height={30} />;
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Image with src "/logo.png" must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `layout="fill"` and `objectFit="contain"` to your `Image` so that it maintains its aspect ratio while filling its container. You can then add a wrapper `div` around the `Image` component and apply the `height` to it instead.

```js
<div style={{ position: 'relative', height: '30px' }}>
    <Image
        src="/logo.png"
        layout="fill"
        objectFit="contain"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still get the wrong width for the image. For example, if I create a page component that only returns the  <img> element, this element is positioned on the left and its width is still respecting the aspect ratio. But if the component returns the <div> + <Image> elements, the image now stretches across the screen.

Comment: @Kazuto_Ute Did you set `objectFit="contain"` as per my example? Here's a sample codesandbox with a working version of my snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-margulis-0zkbs.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, the 2nd img element is stretched across the screen. What if I want the img element width to still respect the aspect ratio instead of stretching?

Comment: Do you know the aspect ratio in advance? You could add `aspectRatio: "<ratio>"` to the container `style` prop if so. Or, alternatively, you'll need to provide an explicit `width` to the container itself, the image would still maintain its aspect ratio though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image used (hence the aspect ratio) could change from time to time. Ideally I would not like to change the code everytime the design team comes up with a new image. So there is no way to not hard-code the width or the aspect ratio in this case?

Comment: I guess we'll never know...